# What is the skimlinks scope and how does it work

Tags: 13.10, scopes

What is the skimlinks scope ( 'more_suggestions-skimlinks.scope)  and what results does it show or what links does it create in the dash.

All I know is skimlinks affiliates links so how does this work with upcoming Ubuntu 13.10 smart scopes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skimlinks is an affiliate links service that shows search results with buyable stuff in the dash. Skimlinks is one of the *Remote Scopes* which get downloaded from a Canonical server (along with Wikipedia and others). To see a list of all remote scopes, check out this file:

https://productsearch.ubuntu.com/smartscopes/v1/remote-scopes

As far as I can see these scopes can currently only be deactivated all together (switch in privacy options) or one by one:

Open the dashs application lens with Super+A. If you don't see the white icons of the dash plugins, select the filter to show them. Now click on Skimlinks and then *Deactivate*.